# Confusing uses of The Indefinite article

Tags: articles

1. I do not recall ***a*** thing I said because I was drunk.

   In the above sentence the speaker doesn't recall anything about he said, that is he recalls 0% of what he said.

   Now compare the use of The Indefinite article in this sentence.
2. I couldn't recall ***a*** formula my teacher gave me to study. So, I scored 9 out of 10 on my Maths test.

   In the above sentence the speaker recalled everything he studied except only one random, indefinite formula.

   So, my question is how do I know which meaning is conveyed by a speaker when he speaks like those above statements?

Comment: Honestly, I think the answer here is tone of voice and context.

Comment: *I do not recall **a thing*** = *I do not recall **anything*** = *I recall **nothing***. If you can reasonably replace ***a*** by ***any***, it's that first meaning. So for your second example to make sense with that interpretation, we'd expect *I couldn't recall **any** formula my teacher gave me to study. So, I scored **zero** out of 10 on my Maths test.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers In the second sentence there is an implication that it was **a particular formula** that the speaker couldn't remember and possibly, to remove ambiguity (which the score of 9 / 10 already does) it could have been written with the definite article **I couldn't recall the formula...**. => I could recall other formulae, but not that one.

Answer (score 1):

It would be in the inflections/emphasis, as well as context.

"I do not recall *a thing* I said because I was drunk."

1. They can't recall "a thing", implying any thing they said.  Their failure to recall was so bad, not only couldn't they recall several things, they couldn't even recall even one thing.
2. It is pretty clear that drunkenness is more likely to harm your recall of everything than of one indefinite think.  The speaker would likely give further clues if they meant a particular thing, like: "I tried to remember the phone number I had recited just an hour earlier.  I could not recall a thing I *just* said because I was drunk!"  Now you have the context to know they mean the latter.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, "a" is the same as "one", i.e. it indicates a number.

1a. I do not recall one thing I said because I was drunk.

Explanation: I could not remember ten things, I said, I could not remember two things I said, or even **one** thing I said.

2a. I couldn't recall one formula my teacher gave me to study. So, I scored 9 out of 10 on my Maths test.

Explanation: The teacher gave me ten formulae to study. Unfortunately I forgot **one** of them and so only got 9 out of ten.

You can think of "a" as meaning "one" in most situations, e.g.
I ate **a** sandwich = I ate **one** sandwich.

---

Remember that before a vowel, we use "an". For example we say "an apple". This "an" was the original pronunciation of "one". We used to say "an" everywhere, even preceding a consonant, for instance, we would have said "an man", meaning "one man".

In many languages "one" and the indefinite article are still the same word. In German the word for "a/an" is "ein" and also the word "ein" is the word meaning "one".